# How to sort the columns of every row of a data frame and then save the column name in the corresponding columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame A.

`A <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,3,1,8,6,7,5,9,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
rownames(A)<-c('Row1','Row2','Row3')
colnames(A)<-c('Col1','Col2','Col3')`

```
A

             Col 1     Col 2     Col 3
Row 1            2         8         5
Row 2            3         6         9
Row 3            1         7         4
```

I want to sort every column of a row in descending order and copy the column name in the respective columns like this.

```
Row 1        Col 2     Col 3     Col 1
Row 2        Col 3     Col 2     Col 1
Row 3        Col 2     Col 3     Col 1
```

I used this code to achieve this.

```
 sorted_users_vs_tags1<-t(apply(sorted_users_vs_tags1, 1, function(row) {
    names(row)<-colnames(sorted_users_vs_tags1)
    row[, order(row, decreasing = TRUE)]
    row<-names(row)})
```

But I am getting an error in dimension length in 2nd line of the function in apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
matrix(colnames(A)[t(apply(A,1,order,decreasing=T))],ncol=3)
```